# Block BSSID with wpa_supplicant in IBSS mode

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network, wpa-supplicant

is it possible to select / whitelist / blacklist a BSSID in IBSS (AdHoc) mode?

The connection must be established using wpa_supplicant because encryption is needed.
I've tried by specifying `bssid`, `bssid_whitelist` and `bssid_blacklist` in the wpa_supplicant configuration file but they are ignored.
Looking at [wpa_supplicant.conf](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf) I see that `bssid` is expected to work only for AP mode, but nothing is said about `bssid_whitelist` and `bssid_blacklist`.
Using `ap_scan=1` is not enough because when wpa_supplicant is started devices may be very distant (or the "bridge" device in the middle may be not running yet).

Is there some other tool to accomplish this? The goal is to prevent the creation of non-communicating (same SSID, different BSSID) AdHoc networks.

Comment: If I recall correctly, IBSSes normally randomly autogenerate their BSSIDs, so it doesn't make any sense to whitelist an IBSS BSSID since you'll never see again, or blacklist BSSIDs you'll never see again, or can't predict, or to blacklist almost all 2^46 of them. In light of that, I'd be shocked if anyone's ever implemented IBSS BSSID blacklisting or whitelisting.

Comment: You are right about random BSSID, but one could write a script to detect the presence of another network (same SSID, different BSSID) and force wpa_supplicant to restart and to connect to the desired BSSID (either via whitelisting or blacklisting)